# How to connect to AWS ECR via CircleCI

Tags: aws-cli, circleci

I'm trying to authenticate a CircleCI pipeline with AWS and I followed this [guide to achieve that](https://circleci.com/blog/openid-connect-identity-tokens/).

The summary of this guide is:

1. Create an OIDC identity provider [image]
2. Add `aws-cli` orb to the CircleCI config.
3. Add a `aws-cli/setup` step.
4. Connect to aws services (only fails at this step).

The result:

> An error occurred (UnrecognizedClientException) when calling the
> GetAuthorizationToken operation: The security token included in the
> request is invalid. Error: Cannot perform an interactive login from a
> non TTY device

Why isn't the pipeline logged in? What am I doing wrong please?

```yaml
version: 2.1
orbs:
  aws-cli: circleci/aws-cli@4.0.0
  aws-ecr: circleci/aws-ecr@8.2.1

jobs:
  build-and-push:
    docker:
      - image: cimg/aws:2023.05
    environment:
      AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: ${AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID}
      AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: ${AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY}
    steps:
      - checkout
      - aws-cli/setup
      - aws-cli/role_arn_setup:
          profile_name: default
          role_arn: arn:aws:iam::7150000000000:role/CI_Role
      - setup_remote_docker
      - run:
          working_directory: ./dotnet-services/user
          name: Create docker image
          command: |
            docker build . --file ./UserService.Api/Dockerfile --tag userservice
            docker tag userservice:latest 715815605776.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/userservice:${CIRCLE_BUILD_NUM}
            # **************** FAILS HERE
            echo "Logging in to ECR... Access key=$AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID"
            aws ecr get-login-password --region eu-west-1 | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin 715815605776.dkr.ecr.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com

workflows:
  build:
    jobs:
      - build-and-push:
          context: aws # contains environment variables
```

A little more context. If I try to use another service other than ECR e.g.

```yaml
aws sts get-caller-identity --profile default
aws s3 ls --profile default
```

Returns:

> An error occurred (InvalidClientTokenId) when calling the AssumeRole operation: The security token included in the request is invalid.

> Exited with code exit status 254

Also, printing the credentials:

```yaml
cat ~/.aws/credentials
```

Returns the below. Shouldn't we have a token too?

```
[default]
aws_access_key_id = ${AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID}
aws_secret_access_key = ${AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY}
```

By the way, the AWS ECR login command works on my machine. Only not on CircleCI.